# Error al iniciar apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

No puedo inciar apache, cada vez que trato el sistema me marca el siguientre error:

> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>     Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>              └─apache2-systemd.conf
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-29 04:53:53 UTC; 29s ago
>     Process: 4439 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>     Process: 13378 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 1756 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> ene 29 04:53:52 mausrv systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv apachectl[13378]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nextcloud.conf:
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv apachectl[13378]: Illegal option followSysmlinks
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv apachectl[13378]: Action 'start' failed.
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv apachectl[13378]: The Apache error log may have more information.
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   ene 29 04:53:53 mausrv systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Que puedo hacer para inicarlo. En ubuntu server.

Comment: Podría ser que tuvieras otro servicio escuchando en el puerto 80. Prueba a ejecutar este comando: sudo ss -ntlp 'sport = 80'.

Comment: A ver... ¿qué pone tu archivo `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nextcloud.conf`? ¿De dónde sale?